# notepad++ highlight colours

Tags: windows-xp, notepad++

I like the highlighting feature in notepad++, but when using certain themes that default purple and yellow make the text unreadable, and it seems I cannot change it through style configurator.
Does anyone know where I would find the option to change these? It's making working with dark themes hard.

running ANSI on XP

actually I was able to change the colors through Style configurator
I used tags match highlight and tags atribute

Comment: Voted to move to superuser.

Comment: I think this was addressed in a newer version of notpad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starter, have you tried 'Settings' > 'Style Configuration' and in pop up, find 'Select theme' drop down box. Choose a theme color that suits you. For example, I'm on 'Deep Black'.

Comment: I like the choco, but need to make the highlights work. would be nice to overwrite the transparency on those.

Comment: Go to 'Style Configurator' pop up, in your selected theme (ie/ Choco), in language choose 'Global Styles' then in style choose 'Selected text color'. Here you can change the 'Background color' value to one that suits you.

Answer (score 5):

At least in notepad++ v6.2.2, some themes, such as Twilight, seem to ignore changes to the "Tag match highlight" and "Tag attribute".  Meaning you end up with very hard to read highlight colors on a dark background.

It seems to be some error in the XML file for the theme.  If you remove, for example, the "edgeColour" entry (which is set to `styleID="0"`) then Notepad++ appears to parse the later entries properly - so the color changes do take effect.

Comment: Weird. I commented out the entire `Edge colour` line and it fixed my highlight issues.

Comment: where is this edgeColour styleID=0 thing?

Answer (score 3):

I needed this too.  As the original poster has noted, you can do this through:

**Settings > Style Configurator > Global Styles ...**

- Tags match highlight
- Tags attribute

Comment: oh of course.... because `Tags Attribute` is a logical thing to call `Selected Text`. 